# How to add gameObject in Canvas without any changes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas, position, scale

I have this C# code in Unity:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

//public GameObject Button;
public Transform Button;
public int rows;
public int columns;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
         x = 170 * rows;
         y = -170 * columns;
        Transform newButton = (Transform)Instantiate (Button, new Vector3(0,0,0), Quaternion.identity);
        newButton.parent = gameObject.transform;
        newButton.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1, 1, 1);
        newButton.transform.parent = GameObject.Find ("Canvas").transform;
        }
    }
}
```

When it is cloning buttons, and transforming to canvas the position of newButton is changing and scale also. What should I do?

Comment: See the duplicate and let me know if that does not work so that I will quickly  re-open it. The behavior is different on Unity versions but you should pass `false` to the `SetParent` function.

Comment: Okay I will try it now

Comment: Did that work? Just want to make sure. If not explain which part does not work.

Comment: `newButton.GetComponent<RectTransorm>().anchoredPosition3D = new Vector2(x,y);` I added this part and it is not recognizing it , RectTransform and anchoredposition are red

Comment: That seems to be another question... What do you mean by *not recognizing it* and *are red*? You can edit your question to add more information and screenshots.

Comment: Hi, it is `SetParent` not `Setparent`. The "P" is capitalized. Also, it is `RectTransform` not `RectTransorm`. Spelling counts when it comes to programming.  In the future, please add **EDIT** to your question then add your new code. Don't change the original code as that would make the answer or duplicate make no sense.

Comment: you mentioned there yourUIobj.GetComponent
by yourUIobj you mean the name of the prefab that I am copying ?

Comment: Not the direct prefab but the one you just instantiated. In this case, that would be `newButton`.  Note that you don't need to set the `anchoredPosition3D` if it is a prefab that you already set the position. Simply doing what's in my first comment or first part of the duplicate should solve your issue. Now, if it is a prefab you have not positioned properly from the Editor, then you have to set the `anchoredPosition3D` and rest of the variables from the duplicate. Please  try this before making further comments.

Comment: I solved this problem 
the solution is this 
`Transform newButton = Instantiate<Transform> (Button);
   newButton.SetParent( GameObject.Find ("Canvas").transform);
   newButton.localScale = Vector3.one;
   newButton.localPosition = new Vector3(x,y,0); 
`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the original position and scale of the cloned button. Use [`Transform.SetParent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html) instead of setting `Transform.parent`. And set the second parameter `worldPositionStays` to `false`.

```
Transform newButton = (Transform)Instantiate (Button, new Vector3(0,0,0), Quaternion.identity);
newButton.localScale = new Vector3 (1, 1, 1);
newButton.SetParent(GameObject.Find ("Canvas").transform, false);
```

Comment: Curious at the downvoter. He/she seems down votes all the posts in U3D group. Any reason doing so?

Comment: Nothing has changed 
Scale got 76.8

Comment: @ManeHambardzumyan Did you remove the second line `newButton.parent = gameObject.transform;`?

Comment: Yes I removed , I will edit my code now

Comment: @zwcloud I saw that. Highly suspect that he is doing so. But he might be too arbitrary. He did not even look through the code and answer. That is why StackOverflow is blamed to be not so friendly. I think this is ridiculous. see this post: https://www.quora.com/Why-do-some-people-hate-Stack-Overflow

Comment: I did not down-vote you. If I did I will tell you that and tell you why. The fact that you thought that and responded with the down-vote on my answer is funny. To David and zwcloud. See [this](http://imgur.com/a/cFJOu) Happy coding.

Comment: @Programmer Sorry. But I should say sometimes your answer is over-complicated

Comment: Guys let's for first solve my problem

Comment: @david i downvoted it, and it was by accident. clumsy fingers go mobile :S